# Magnetic field & quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

I am having difficulty understanding what the effects of an applied magnetic field would be on paramagnetic, diamagnetic or ionic species.

Many books on magnetism refer to the magnetization force, which according to quantum mechanics can do work on particles with intrinsic magnetic moment (one example is Chapter 8 of Griffiths' book "Introduction to Electrodynamics").

The magnetization force is
$F_M=\nabla ($**m**$ \cdot $**B**$)$, where **m** is the magnetic moment and **B** is the magnetic field.

According to this equation, a paramagnetic particle with an intrinsic magnetic moment would move in the direction of the magnetic field. Specifically, for a paramagnetic material **m** $=$ $\chi$ **H** where $\chi$ is the magnetic susceptibility and **H** is the magnetic field strength. Therefore, $F_M$ would be in the direction of the magnetic field. An example of this is the oxygen molecule which has a total spin of 1.

However, the experiment of Stern–Gerlach comes to mind which shows the behaviour of electrons in a non-uniform magnetic field. Due to their spin being 0.5 or -0.5, they can end up travelling along the direction of the magnetic field or the opposite direction (assuming we cancel the Lorentz force). So I would expect the same behaviour for an oxygen molecule which has two unpaired electrons!

So what causes the different kinetics of an oxygen molecule, moving along the magnetic field, and an electron, moving either along or in the opposite direction of the magnetic field?